# Как осуществлять взаимодействие сайта и мобильного приложения?

Tags: java, android

Хочу написать мобильное приложение для сайта у которого нет API. Каким образом мне осуществлять тогда взаимодействие с сайтом, например, чтобы выполнить регистрацию на сайте. 
Создать своё API? Тогда на чем его писать, что можно почитать на эту тему? Мобильное приложение пишу на Java.

Comment: Парсить, парсить и еще раз парсить. jsoup.org

Answer (score 0):

Как самый простой вариант - использовать WebView + мобильную или адаптивную версию сайта. Регистрация, авторизация будет происходить на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Нормальных вариантов 2

1) Адаптировать сайт под `мобильную версию` (оптимальная версия)

Основной плюсы: Модернизировать и обновлять сайт просто. Мультиплатформенность.

Основной минусы: Высокий трафик. Загруженность. Плохо для людей, которые платят за интернет по количеству трафика.

2) Создать `мобильное приложение`

Основные плюсы: Все стили уже есть в шаблонах и их ненужно подгружать (снижение трафика). Структура запросов к БД храниться в приложение. Возможна работа при плохом интернете или при полном его отсутствие (если информация, загруженная из БД сохраняется в кэше).

Основные минусы: Для каждой версии ОС придётся писать своё приложение. Приложение занимает место в памяти телефона. Пользователю нужно потратить время, чтобы скачать и установить приложение на телефон. Ошибки, возникающие в работе приложения сложнее устранить.

Вы хотите пойти по 2 варианту. Во-первых, у сайта должна быть база данных. Об этом вы не упомянули, так что думаю, что у вас её нет. В любом случае, вам нужно решить, как будет выглядеть ваша мобильная версия сайта. Если нет БД, тогда можно парсить текст с оригинального сайта и выводить его в мобильном приложение. Если же БД у вас есть, тогда своё приложение вы можете построить на запросах к ней.

Comment: Дело в том, что я хочу написать для стороннего сайта и не знаю есть ли у него БД

Comment: Тогда парсить. В вашем случае это единственный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для таких целей пишут сервер работающий через RESTful API. В сети есть множество материалов на эту тему - посмотрите.